# Unexpected static variable behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, static-members

here is sample of my code

```
internal static class Communication
{
    ...

    private static byte _lastAnswer;

    ...

    static void Serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (SerialDataLock)
            {
                ...
                 _lastAnswer = data[0];
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Serial_DataReceived` is handler for `SerialPort.DataReceived` event and data is local byte array grabbed from serial port. Problem is in unexpected behaviour of `_lastAnswer`. Debugger shows sometimes it is not assigned and sometimes it is assigned but by the end of the block suddenly returns to it's previous value.

For example I try to read `_lastAnswer` through public property in main thread

```
public static byte LastAnswer
    {
        get
        {
            Program.DataRecievedEvent.Reset(); 
            byte rtn = _lastAnswer;
            _lastAnswer = ErrorCode;
            Debug.Assert(rtn!=0xff);
            _lastAnswer = 0xff; //return member to default value
            return rtn;
        }
    }
```

`Assert` doesn't throws any exception, but the next block in Main `if (answer == 0xff)` returns true

After a day I have found out that making field `_lastAnswer` non static in other non static class and referencing it solves the problem. But that looks awful and doesn't give answer to the topic.

Comment: A debugger isn't going to be entirely reliable in a multithreaded application.  C# isn't designed to guarantee observable orderings of much at all outside of single threaded situations.  Instead show how the program itself is acting improperly.

Comment: Try making _lastAnswer volatile. **private static volatile byte _lastAnswer**

Comment: @Alan It doesn't need to be volatile if it's always accessed from within a `lock` block.

Comment: @Alan that haven't done much work

Comment: @Servy not only debugger but the code next to shown block behaves abnormally

Comment: @rum Well, without knowing what the code is, what the observed behavior is, how you observed it, etc. then there isn't much for us to do.

Comment: @Servy for example `Debug.Assert(_lastAnswer!=0xFF)` doesn't lead to assert but `if(_lastAnswer==0xFF)` in next block works...

Comment: @rum Again, you haven't shown the code.  If that's all within a `lock`, *and all access to that variable is locked on the same object*, then there is something off, unless you have some other problem with how you're accessing the variable.

Comment: @Servy here is the code [Form1.cs](http://pastebin.com/wkW5QD6a) and [Communication.cs](http://pastebin.com/KqPNb5x1)

Comment: @rum Please include a *short* but *complete* example *in the question itself* that demonstrates the problem.  I'm not going to sift through hundreds of lines of unrelated code just to pull out what's relevant, and it's also important for questions to be complete and self sufficient without being reliant on external resources.

Comment: @Servy That's not true, just because he locked on an unrelated object does not mean that the volatile keyword is not needed. But, I assume he has multiple other problems with his code.

Comment: @Alan If all access to the variable is with `lock` statements, then `volatile` isn't needed, which is what I said before.  The only way `volatile` would matter is if it was accessed outside of a `lock` block, and in that case that comment wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the variable without locking on it.  This can have any number of problems.

1. There is no memory barrier introduced in your second code snippet, and as a result the CPU is allowed to make optimizations that aren't legal in a multithreaded context.  (It can use cached values of the variable without updating them as often as you may think it should be.)
2. There is nothing preventing the first code snippet from mutating the variable after you've grabbed it the first time, and before you've grabbed it a second time.

You should be locking on *the same object that you lock on when manipulating the variable in the first snippet* when accessing it in the second snippet.

Comment: @rum Are you changing the variable anywhere else that *isn't* locking on that same object?

Comment: @rum Also, keep in mind that setting `_lastAnswer` to `0xff` doesn't set `rtn` to that value, or result in that value being returned, so whatever is accessing the variable externally isn't seeing that change.

Comment: Yes, I consider that basic types are affected by value not by reference. The variable is changed only in handler and property.